# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im running following code, it will display error message. How to solve this error?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Testresult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String testresult(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @Valid TestCustomer<Customer> req
               ,BindingResult resultMsg) 
     {
        String content = "";
        if(resultMsg.hasFieldErrors() ){
            System.out.println("the error counts:" + resultMsg.getErrorCount());

        }
        return resultMsg.getErrorCount;
    }

//TestCustomer.java

public class TestCustomer<T> extends BaseUser {

    @Valid
    private T req;

    public T getReq() {
        return req;
    }

    public void setReq(T req) {
        this.req = req;
    }

}

//BaseUser.java
public class BaseUser {

    @Size(min=3, max=20)
    private String app;

    public String getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public void setApp(String app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
}
//Customer.java
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    @Size(min=3, max=4)
    private String cust_id;

    private String order_id;

    public String getCust_id() {
        return cust_id;
    }

    public void setCust_id(String cust_id) {
        this.cust_id = cust_id;
    }

    public String getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(String order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }
}
```

I post following url

> http://localhost:8080/jd/order/Testresult?app=122&req={\"cust_id\":\"\", \"order_id\":\"122\"}

The firefox poster error is:

> /*
>       [
>        "timestamp": 1436514495544,
>        "status": 500,
>        "error": "Internal Server Error",
>        "exception": "org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException",
>        "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'cn.vcredit.jd.emergencymoney.restservice.TestCustomer'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [cn.vcredit.jd.emergencymoney.restservice.TestCustomer]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"]
>   */

Comment: from your error log it seems like you are passing String while calling url :-/Testresult

Comment: How does you data - a `String` - get converted into a `TestCustomer`? You seem to have not defined any method by which this could happen.

Comment: You are passing your json req as query string not in request body.